# Are there any problems with this timezone approach?

Tags: sql-server-2005, coldfusion, timezone

Adding timezone support to an event management system using [TimeZone-CFC](https://github.com/rip747/TimeZone-CFC). The approach I am taking has the user select the event timezone and enter datetimes based on that timezone. The datetimes are converted to the server's timezone on save. Before presenting the datetimes back to the user they are converted to the event's timezone.

For example on save...

```
<cfqueryparam value="#application.tz.castToServer(eventStartDateTime, eventTimeZone)#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_timestamp" />
```

then when presenting datetime back to the user it is first converted to event timezone like this...

```
<cfset eventStartTime = application.tz.castFromServer(startDateTime, eventTimeZone) />
```

Internally dates are compared without regard to the event's timezone, for example if an email is scheduled to go out just compare current server datetime to datetime from datebase record.

Are there any known problems with this approach, daylight savings time issue, edge cases, etc, or is a standard way of going about it?

Comment: not entirely sure what approach you use, but most ppl save the datetime in DB in UTC, so you get the best 'resolution' so to speak.  Not sure if this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally if the event timezone's are different per event you want to store all times, in UTC format then only convert them for display purposes. This way when you convert them they are displayed correctly and can take into account daylight savings etc.

If you store them in the event timezone and the event timezone crosses daylight savings for example, the times in the database are now wrong.

If the events are always in a single timezone with no daylight savings, it would be fine.